# StreamCorruptedException при Сериализации

Tags: java, сериализация

Есть класс(Example) который реализует интерфейс Serializable

Есть file - он пустой

Есть такой код

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
(Example) inputStream.readObject());
```

Так вот:
если в классе Example я определяю только метод equals, то при чтении он выкидывает EOFExeption и я определяю что файл пуст, если в классе я реализовываю и equals, и hashCode то он мне выкидывает ошибку StreamCorruptedException.
Файл в дальнейшем будет заполнен данными, но смысл в том, что с 2 методами он выкидывает непонятную мне ошибку, я ее не знаю как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в вопросе не хватает минимально воспроизводимого примера.

Если посмотреть в документацию по исключениям:

> public class EOFException
>
> Signals that an end of file or end of stream
>   has been reached unexpectedly during input.

**`EOFException`** - сигнализирует о внезапно закончившемся потоке для чтения

> public class StreamCorruptedException
>
> Thrown when control information that was read from an object stream
>   violates internal consistency checks.

**`StreamCorruptedException`** - выбрасывается когда прочитанная информация не соответствует ожиданиям (вольный перевод)

Т.е. если читающий поток ожидает системную информацию и за ней данные об объекте, а получает что-то другое

Ждет:

```
системная информация -> данные объекта 1 -> данные объекта 2 ...
```

Получает:

```
системная информация -> данные объекта 1 -> системная информация...
```

На пустом файле у меня всегда выбрасывался EOFException в не зависимости от наличия `hashCode` или `equals`